# Backbone Collection Can't Remove Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-forms

I've got a Backbone Model called Delivery. I then create a collection of Deliveries called DeliveryList backed by LocalStorage. In my Marionette.ItemView for displaying items in the collection, I have a method to remove items:

```
    removeDeliveryOption: function() {
        Deliveries.remove(this.model.get("id"));
    }
```

For some reason, this removes the item from the Marionette.CompositeView when I click the remove button, but when I reload the page the same number of items always reappear.

It's worth noting that when I delete the item, it always reappears with the default optionName "Free Delivery". I'm using both defaults and a schema in the model because I'm using the Backbone-forms plugin (https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var Delivery = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            order: Deliveries.nextOrder(),
            optionName: "Free Delivery",
            shipToState: "Hawaii",
            zipCodes: "96813",
            perOrderFee: "0.00",
            perItemFee: "0.00"
        };
    },

    schema: {
        optionName: { type: 'Text', validators: ['required'] },
        shipToState: { type: 'Select', options: getStateNames(), validators: ['required'] },
        zipCodes: { type: 'Text', validators: ['required'] },
        perOrderFee: { type: 'Text', validators: ['required'] },
        perItemFee: { type: 'Text', validators: ['required'] },
    }

});

var DeliveryList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Delivery,

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("deliverylist-backbone"),

    nextOrder: function () {
        if (!this.length) return 1;
        return this.last().get('order') + 1;
    },

    comparator: 'order'
});
var Deliveries = new DeliveryList;

var deliveryView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    //tagName: "li",
    template: "#delivery-item-template",

    events: {
        "click #removeThis": "removeDeliveryOption",
    },

    removeDeliveryOption: function() {
        Deliveries.remove(this.model.get("id"));
    }
});

var DeliveriesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        Deliveries.fetch();
    },

    template: '#deliveries-view-template',

    itemView: deliveryView,

    events: {
        "click #addShipping": "addDeliveryOption",
    },

    addDeliveryOption: function() {
        var editDeliveryForm = new Backbone.Form({
            template: _.template($("#editDeliveryTemplate").html()),
            model: Deliveries.create()
        }).render();

        this.$el.append(editDeliveryForm.el);

        $("#triggerEditDelivery").fancybox({
            'afterClose': function () {
                commitForm(editDeliveryForm);
                //Wait do display the inlineModel until here

                // Once we've bound the form to the model, put the saving logic with the collection
                //Deliveries.last().save();
            }
        }).trigger('click');
    },

    // Specify a jQuery selector to put the itemView instances in to
    itemViewContainer: "#deliveries",
});
```

EDIT
Thanks to @ejosafat! Had to destroy the model instead of just removing from collection.

```
removeDeliveryOption: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remove method only affects the collection loaded in the browser, not in the permanent storage (local or server). That's why it dissappears from the view but when you reload the page it appears again.

If you want to get rid of that model in the storage too, use its destroy method.

(btw, it's a common convention in Javascript to use initial capital letter only for constructor functions, as clue that it should be used with the new operator, or be extended to create a derived constructor/class, so it's a bad idea to use Deliveries as a collection var name)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! That worked, see my Edit above. I still don't understand why it would be saving to the server, I have the collection backed by the LocalStorage plugin. Any thoughts on where it would be saving to the server?

Comment: It's saving via LocalStorage. I said 'server' because I read your question too quickly and I skipped the mention to the plugin :-). anyway, the behavior of remove/destroy methods is the same. Only destroy will remove the model definitely from the permanent storage whether it's browser local storage or a backend server.